# Python - How to create a list from an excel column

Tags: pandas

I have a list of names in one column of a csv file. I'm trying to make this into a list in python that looks like

```
list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
```

and so on.

I have the following

```
import pandas as pd
export = pd.read_csv('Top100.csv', header=None)
```

but I can't figure out how to pull out the information and put it into a list format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below is applicable if your data is in a vertical column

```
export = pd.read_csv('Top100.csv', header=None)
export.values.T[0].tolist()
```

The `.T` in this transposes the values, as normally pandas is row oriented. Then you take the [0] index because Pandas reads excel or csv sheets in as a matrix, even if there's only a single column. Call the `tolist()` method on it and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Read csv will return a pandas dataframe so your columns can be accessed through the dataframe.  Say your file has columns "A", "B", "C"

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Top100.csv', header=None)
print data["a"]
```

Or as a list

```
print list(data["a"])
```